# How can I search Json files stored in my s3 bucket from my local computer?

Tags: amazon-s3, grep, command-line-interface

I have thousands of json files stored in my s3 bucket and need to perform a grep search for the string "name".

I have configured AWS cli ok as i can print out all the files in bucket (via the ls command).

I have tried the 2 following commands:

1)

```
aws s3 ls s3://training | grep 'name'
```

This resulted in nothing

2)

```
aws s3 cp s3://training/*json - | grep 'name'
```

This gave the error:

> download failed: s3://training/*json to - An error occurred (404)
>   when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found

I know the string name exists 100% as it is a field name that is stated multiple times in each json

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your first example fails because you are listing the objects, rather than printing out the content of the objects.

Your second example fails because you cannot use wildcards with S3 requests.

One way to do this would be to sync the files locally, then grep the local files, then delete the local files (or just leave them in place to optimize future syncs). You can use `aws s3 sync` to do this.

Another option would be to use [Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) to query the JSON content. You can use SQL queries, for example.

Another option would be to create a search index when documents are uploaded to S3. You could trigger a Lambda function which reads the object content and indexes that into another S3 object, or a DynamoDB table, or even Elasticsearch if this is a significant system.